# Problem binding events with canvas's create_window widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm new to Tkinter and I'm trying to make a movable widget inside a canvas widget similar to below.

I want to use `create_window` to make a widget inside canvas and bind events to it.

My problem is when I use `create_oval()` or `create_line()`, the event handlers work and I can drag the object, but when I try it with `create_window()` like below, `start_drag()` and `drag()` are never reached when I click on the widget and drag it with my mouse.

```
class DraggableWidget:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.start_x, self.start_y = 0, 0
        image = tk.PhotoImage(file=img_path) # omit img_path here
        label = tk.Label(self.canvas, image=image)
        self.label_id = self.canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label, anchor="nw")             #!work
        # self.label_id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,10,10, outline="black", fill="red") #work

        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.label_id , "<Button-1>", self.start_drag)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.label_id, "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)

    def start_drag(self, event):
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

    def drag(self, event):
        dx = event.x - self.start_x
        dy = event.y - self.start_y
        self.canvas.move(self.window, dx, dy)
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, hopefully someone can help me correct my mistakes.

Comment: I think you need to bind to the widget rather than through the canvas.  Though, if all you're doing is displaying an image, you might want to consider creating the image directly on the canvas rather than embedding a label.

Comment: Thanks! I can use lambda and pass the object Id to the callback to bind to the widget instead, and creating the image directly on the canvas would be easier. But I want to know why would the above not work or if anyone else have had the same problem and I plan to add additional widgets to the label.

Comment: The mouse events are triggered on the label, so you need to bind on the label instead.

Comment: Typo: missing commas `(self.label_id id,` should be `(self.label_id, id,`

Comment: line 10, in __init__
    self.label_id = self.canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label, anchor="nw")             #!work  .....AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_window'

Comment: What is this self.canvas = canvas? Canvas is root object. But you calling this self.canvas.create_window i w/out  tk.Canvas

Comment: toyota Supra I want self.canvas to be a refenrece to a canvas widget passed to this class from another class. tk.Canvas will be called prior to this class.

Comment: acw1668 It seems that you are right, it works when I bind the event to the label instead of to the child widget of canvas. I guess the docs https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html#creating forgot to mention it.